# Какой профит дают буферы boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Для чего нужны boost::asio::const_buffer / mutable_buffer - какой от них профит по сравнению со стандартными массивами/векторами? Единственное что увидел - они приводят данные к указателю на байт. Можете подробнее объяснить преимущества недостатки этих сущностей? Ну и советы когда лучше их применять, а когда не стоит.

p.s. я так понимаю ConstBufferSequence - более общая сущность для всех буферов?

Comment: А что вас не устраивает в описании этих классов в документации?

Comment: Создание отдельного типа для конкретной задачи (если все сделано правильно) очень сильно улучшает шансы, что компилятор вычислит ошибку ещё в момент написания. std::chrono тому большущий пример.